# Changing Background color with focuslistener in Java

Tags: java, swing, focuslistener

I am trying to set up and have my jpanel's background color change, everytime when focus is gained and lost, but I can't seem to get it right. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class 7UpsPanel extends JFrame {
  private JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

  public MyFrame() {
    super("Lab 5 - Part 1");
    //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLocation(100, 100);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    FocusListener focused = new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
      };

    jpanel.addFocusListener(focused);
    add(jpanel);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  That code would need imports and a main method to put it on screen, to be an MCVE.  2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how it goes wrong, exactly. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Try `jpanel.setFocusable(true);`.  Panels are not focusable by default.  But on a wider note, I'd do this using a `JButton`.  A button is focusable by default, and has inbuilt methods to change icons for a range of conditions (focused, pressed etc.). If it was specified exactly this way by a teacher (or boss), they need a good smack up the side of the head..

Answer (score 0):

You have a sequence of problems here. I'll go through them one by one.

First of all, I see that you have a class named "7UpsPanel". I'm not sure which compiler is even allowing this, but officially it's against the Java Specification for any identifier to begin with a literal number (against most specifications, actually). It would be better to call it "SevenUpsPanel". This is a little tangential to your question, though.

Andrew Thompson is right, that JPanels are not, by themselves, focusable. This is by design. You can change that (on a panel-by-panel basis) with the `setFocusable(boolean)` method, which should go right before your `addFocusListener(…)` call.

Additionally, your `setBackground(…)` calls are referencing the `JFrame`'s `setBackground()`, not your panel's. To properly change the color of the panel, they should look more like:

```
jpanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Lastly, changing the background color doesn't qualify as an invalidation interrupt. You have to trigger it manually, or rather, write in the automation. This means that, at the end of each `FocusListener` method, you must have (at minimum):

```
repaint();
```

Or, any other method known to internally trigger a repaint. This method calls `paint(Graphics g)` and `paintComponents(…)` in the necessary order to redraw your frame.

Lastly, don't add the panel like that. You would, in this instance, want to make it your content pane. Adding the pane the way you are provides no guarantee of it having a visible area; content panes take up the area of the frame (minus insets of course).

Lastly, those two TODOs are reminders that you haven't written anything into the auto-generated methods. You clearly have, and to leave them in, well, that just defeats the point of it all.

Here's my remake of your program, just to give you an idea what I mean:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SevenUpsPanel extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SevenUpsPanel();
    }

    private JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();

    public SevenUpsPanel() {
        super("Lab 5 - Part 1");
        setLocation(100, 100);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        FocusListener focused = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
//              jpanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK); // Assuming an old command?
                jpanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                jpanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                repaint();
            }

        };

        jpanel.setFocusable(true);
        jpanel.addFocusListener(focused);

        setContentPane(jpanel);

    }
}
```

`JPanel`s are tricky, they aren't like other `JComponent`s. Take a look at the documentation, comparing `JPanel`'s inheritance with, say, `JButton`, when you have a moment, and I'm sure you'll see why. They make great canvases but when it comes to focus listening, it's often better to use something like an undecorated `JButton` or even a `JTextField`.

Best of luck, and I hope this helps.